# JBoss 7: No EJB receiver available

Tags: ejb, jboss7.x

I'm pretty newbie with JBoss 7. I'm facing strange behaviour. Sometimes, when I try to invoke a session bean, I run into the following exception:

```
com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract java.util.List myServlet.getData() throws myException' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No EJB receiver available for handling [appName:myAppNameEE,modulename:myModuleEJB,distinctname:] combination for invocation context org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext@3e23bd28
```

It usually happens when run my GWT application from Eclipse. The exception does not occur always. Sometimes it occurs fewer than others. Sometimes it occurs pretty every time I call a session bean and it's a pain. I read tutorial (https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI?_sscc=t) and I am pretty sure to have the jboss-ejb-client.properties in the right place.

my jboss-ejb-client looks like:

`endpoint.name=myAppEE/myAppEJB
    remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false
    remote.connections=default
    remote.connection.default.host=localhost
    remote.connection.default.port = 4447
    remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false`

it is located in:

`myAppEJB\ejbModule\com\myApp\ejb\conf`

The businness delegate:

```
public class myAppServerDelegate extends ServerDelegate{

private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(myAppServerDelegate.class.getName());
private myAppRemote theSession = null;

public myAppServerDelegate() throws Exception {

    try {
        theSession = (myAppRemote) getJndiContext().lookup(getJindiLookupName(myAppServerDelegate.class, myAppRemote.class));
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        throw (e);
    }
}

public List<myDataDTO> getAllmyDataBy(String a, String b,
        String c, String d,Integer e,
        Integer f) throws ServerDelegateException {

        return theSession.getAllmyDataBy(a, b, c, d,e,f);
}

public Integer getCountmyDataBy(String a, String b, String c, String d) throws ServerDelegateException {

    return theSession.getCountmyDataBy(a, b, c, d);
}
...

public String getServiceMessage() {

    return theSession.getServiceMessage();
}

...
}
```

The session bean:

```
@Stateless

public class myAppSession implements myAppRemote {

private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(myAppSession.class.getName());
@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager entityManager;
@EJB
private myAppHomeLocal beanmyApp;

...

public String getServiceMessage() {

    return "MESSAGGIODISERVIZIO";
}

public List<myDataDTO> getAllmyDataBy(String a,String b,
        String c, String d,Integer e,
        Integer f) throws ServerDelegateException {

    logger.info("myAppSession.getAllmyDataBy.");
    List<myData> entityList = findByParms(a, b, c, d,e,f);
    return myDataAssemblyDTO.getmyDataDTOList(entityList);
}

public Integer getCountmyDataBy(String a,String b, String c, String d) throws ServerDelegateException {

    return findByParmsCount(a, b, c, d);
}
...
}
```

The servlet:

```
...
```

@SuppressWarnings("serial")

public class MyGenericServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements MyGenericService {

```
private MyAppServerDelegate myAppServerDelegate = null;

public MyGenericServiceImpl() throws Exception{
    super();
    myAppServerDelegate = new MyAppServerDelegate();
}

private MyAppServerDelegate getDelegate()    {
    return myAppServerDelegate;
}

private myGWTException buildLocalExceptionFromServerException(ServerDelegateException sde)    {
    myGWTException x = new myGWTException();
    x.setParms(sde.guiMessage,sde.timestamp,sde.tipoEvento);
    return x;
}

@Override
public PagingLoadResult<myDataBean> getAllmyDataBy(String a, String b, String c, PagingLoadConfig plc) throws MyGWTException {
    try    {
        String cs = ((UserSessionBean)this.getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().getAttribute("user")).getCodiceStudio();
        List<myDataBean> tsb = MyDataClientAssembly.getMyDataBeanList(myAppServerDelegate.getAllmyDataBy(cs, a, b, c, plc.getOffset(), plc.getLimit()));
        return new BasePagingLoadResult<MyDataBean>(tsb, plc.getOffset(), myDataServerDelegate.getCountmyDataBy(cs, a, b, c));
    } catch (ServerDelegateException sde)    {
        throw buildLocalExceptionFromServerException(sde);
    }
}

@Override
public String getServiceMessage() {
    return getDelegate().getServiceMessage();
}

@Override
public Integer getCountmyDataBy(String a, String b, String c) throws AmbrogioGWTException {
    try    {
        String cs = ((UserSessionBean)this.getThreadLocalRequest().getSession().getAttribute("user")).getCs();
        return myAppServerDelegate.getCountmtDataBy(cs, a, b, c);
    } catch (ServerDelegateException sde)    {
        throw buildLocalExceptionFromServerException(sde);
    }
}
}
```

The serverdelegate:

```
public class ServerDelegate {

static public String getJindiLookupName( Class<?> theBeanClass, Class<?> theSessionClass) throws NamingException    {
    String jbossServerName = System.getProperty("jboss.server.name");
    if (jbossServerName== null ||  "".equals(jbossServerName)){
        return "myAppEE/myAppEJB/"+ theBeanClass.getSimpleName() + "!" + theSessionClass.getName();
    }else{
        return "java:global/myAppEE/myAppEJB/" + theBeanClass.getSimpleName() + "!" + theSessionClass.getName();
    }       
}

static public Context getJndiContext() throws NamingException    {
    System.out.println("ServerDelegate.getJndiContext");
    final Properties jndiProperties = new Properties();
    String jbossServerName = System.getProperty("jboss.server.name");
    if (jbossServerName== null ||  "".equals(jbossServerName)){
        jndiProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.class.getName());
        jndiProperties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://localhost:4447");
        jndiProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
jndiProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT", "false");
        }             
    return new InitialContext(jndiProperties);       
    }
}
```

I can't figure out what's going on. TIA.

Francesco

Comment: I dig more into the problem. When I deploy gwt .war and ejb .jar under JBoss as an .ear module everything works fine. But, if I run the gwt module under Eclipse's embedded Jetty and ejb module under JBoss, I got the _No EJB Receiver_ exception.

Comment: Anyone? Maybe I lack some infos?

Answer (score 2):

It could be an issue of using the Local vs Remote interface or a connection issue.

Try enabling the `TRACE` log level on the `org.jboss.ejb.client` package. If you already have a `log4j.properties` in your classpath, include this line:

```
log4j.logger.org.jboss.ejb.client=TRACE
```

[This post](https://community.jboss.org/thread/200348) includes other clues for debugging the JBoss EJB client.

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of dependencies I had to include in my mavens pom.xml file. These include

1. jboss-ejb-client
2. xnio-nio
3. jboss-remote-naming
4. jboss-sasl
5. jboss-transaction-ap
6. jboss-marshalling
7. jboss-marshalling-river

I was able to successfully make my remote request from my standalone java client however I do see the following issues

Jboss 7.1: 
13:43:25,028 INFO  [stdout] (EJB default - 6) Hello world
13:43:25,825 ERROR [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (Remoting "mycomputername" read-1) JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

My java ejb client: 
 WARN [Remoting "client-endpoint" task-2] (ChannelAssociation.java:320) - Unsupported message received with header 0xffffffff

Reading online people seem to have solved this by updating the version of certain jars. However, I have yet to find a successful solution.

Update: I included the jboss-client.jar in my classpath when deploying a standalone ejb client. Works great.

java -classpath "$JBOSS_HOME/bin/client/jboss-client.jar;./my-ejb-client.jar" com.test.Myclient

Answer (score 0):

In the class MyAppServerDelegate, you will have to instantiate the attribute "theSession" in the following methods rather than in the constructor:

- getAllmyDataBy();
- getCountmyDataBy();
- getServiceMessage();

The result of theSession method invocation should be stored in a temporary variable, and afterwards call getJndiContext().close(), and then return the temporary value.

Every connection has to be explicitly closed. Indeed, the exception occurs when the maximum number of allowed connections has been reached.